# Magento - No date part in '' found

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, custom-error-handling

Logged into magento this morning and tried to view a customers account who said they were having trouble with my site, they weren't sure if there order was going through or not.

i am navigating to Customer > Manage Customers

When i search, her details appear and i an see her ZIP, email, name etc so it must be saved. I am just trying to simply get into the customer information so i can look at her details.

I read that apparently it might be a locale problem, something to do with the date formatting.
when I click the customer and try to view the account I get the following error;

```
#0 /domains/**********/http/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(1091): Zend_Date->_calculate('set', false, NULL, 'en_GB')
#1 /domains/**********/http/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(210): Zend_Date->set(false, NULL, 'en_GB')
#2 /domains/**********/http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(520): Zend_Date->__construct(false, NULL, Object(Zend_Locale))
#3 /domains/**********/http/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php(91): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->storeDate('19', false, true)
```

originally goes on for 36 lines

Answer (score 1):

Edit file: /lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php and try to add the verification of $number. Sometimes it's empty.

```
if (!empty($number) && count($splitted[0]) == 0) {
     self::_setEncoding($oenc);
     #require_once 'Zend/Locale/Exception.php';
     throw new Zend_Locale_Exception("No date part in '$date' found.");
}
```